# What should I add to the hyperlink?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, hyperlink

If I got a URL which was youtube.com/watch?v=Hj57OP5C-ls .. what should I add in in the code?

```
- (IBAction)btnYoutube:(id)sender {

    NSURL *linkToAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"youtube://user/%@",@"toyotaleasing"]];
    NSURL *linkToWebURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/user/%@",@"toyotaleasing"]];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:linkToAppURL]) {
        // Can open the youtube app URL so launch the youTube app with this URL
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToAppURL];
    }
    else{
        // Can't open the youtube app URL so launch Safari instead
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToWebURL];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this :-)

```
- (IBAction)btnYoutube:(id)sender { 

   NSURL *linkToAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"youtube://watch?v=Hj57OP5C-ls"]; 
   NSURL *linkToWebURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hj57OP5C-ls"]; 

   if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:linkToAppURL]) { 
        // Can open the youtube app URL so launch the youTube app with this URL 
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToAppURL]; 
    } else{ 
       // Can't open the youtube app URL so launch Safari instead 
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToWebURL]; 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Great :) happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSURL *linkToAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"youtube://video/%@",@"Hj57OP5C-ls"]];
NSURL *linkToWebURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@",@"Hj57OP5C-ls"]]
```

Comment: It gives me two threats: Unused variable 'linkToAppURL' and Unused variable 'linkToWebURL'

Comment: @Samia : Why it's displaying unused variable. as it is being used for checking conditions.

Comment: I'm kinda lost, can you tell me more, please?

Comment: @Samia Is it not navigating to Safari or Youtube ?

Comment: The link should go to youtube application that is downloaded in iPhone, if it's not, it will open the youtube url at Safari on iPhone.

Comment: @Samia :Yeah, then what is issue you're facing ?

Comment: I got a thread "0x78a7c:  ldr    r2, [r2].                . Thread 1 :breakpoint 1.1"